# Tiledmap stays dark after world rotation in Phaser

Tags: rotation, phaser-framework, tiled

I want to create a top down game, on which the "camera" rotates with the character (like in Tap Tap Dash). But Phaser does not implement camera rotation, so I followed [this thread](http://www.html5gamedevs.com/topic/6414-rotate-camera/) to create a world group, which will be rotated.

As you can see in the following screenshot, after rotating the Tilemaps (the road and the arrows) as well as the sprites (the coins), black areas occur. What is really strange is that the sprites are rendered correctly as you can see on the bottom of the screenshot, but the Tilemaps are not fully rendered.

[image: Black areas]

I have tried to resize the world again and trying all kind of methods of the camera, world and layer object. But I am out of ideas. Hopefully someone can give me a hint how to approach this problem.

Thank you!